# React & Django - How can I automatically reflect server changes on front-end?

Tags: python, django, reactjs, rest, api

Looking for a bit of advice.

I have a current architecture of Django and PostgreSQL, where a whole lot of activity is happening to the data via the ORM, through scheduled jobs. The data on the backend is being processed and updated on roughly 30 second intervals.

The data is available to the front-end through a bunch of DRF serialisers (basic REST API). This is just being piped to standard HTML templates at the moment.

I'd like the React front-end to mirror this behaviour, and am looking for best-practice advice on how this is typically done. I know in practice how this works in other frameworks but am not certain of doing this well (namely, connecting React's DOM automation to server-side updates).

(I don't want to get involved with websockets, at all.)

Theoretically, I understand there is two ways to do this:

- Front-end AJAX polling the API for new data
- HTTP/2 Server Push
- *Something* built into React that will load stuff in incrementally?

Appreciate the advice - (short examples would be really helpful if possible).

Comment: If you don't want to change anything in the architecture then `polling` is the way to go. but it's expensive due to the amount of request-response cycles. You can try websockets if that can be enabled at your end.

Comment: as suggested when i implimented polling, server load was too high it used to crash when users increase so we switched to websockets with django channels which is super smooth..

Comment: Okay good advice - do you have any advice on how Django Channels interacts with a React front-end? How would it achieve the dynamism I'm going for?

Comment: Best advice is to use: https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use Django channels, documentation is great btw.
[Django Channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Next what is for you is connect React on some event from models, when you save something in model or create new instance after method save, call channels to expose that object in some group. Of course you need to write URL-s where you will be able to get response from channels.

Comment: Would you say that React was even necessary if using channels, if I'm just trying to create a live server feed?

Comment: If you don't need to display data to front end interface then React is not necessary.

Comment: Would it be possible to render the data to a HTML template without using something like React? Could I theoretically just pipe the data into a HTML template using a small piece of JS?

Comment: Yes you can with JavaScript or jQuery. Just open the link I gave to you and learn tutorial.